# Queryset-like filtering of object collection in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm looking for a way to easily filter from a collection of Model objects without hitting the database each time. By definition, QuerySets are lazy and always will hit the DB. So I am wondering if there is anything existing that can do this. If not, perhaps its a good library to create.

For example:

```
all_records = object_set(Record.objects.filter(company=user.company))
```

`object_set` being a hypothetical function which would gather all of the objects in a QuerySet as static data. The result would be an "object manager" instance that could have filters run against it similar to QuerySet filters. This would be particularly useful in storing creating, updating, and deleting objects based on data from multidimensional lists of data.

```
for row in data:
  for col in row:
    # this would not hit the DB. Only filter within the "object_set" in memory.
    all_records.filter(date=col.date, type=col.type, creator=col.user)
```

I realize I may be trying to solve this the wrong way, but regardless, I think this would be a great tool to have in Django. Does anyone know of an existing library or functionality within Django that would solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the QuerySet's select_related method is what you want:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Almost, but the result would still be a qs which would hit the db on every filter or get call.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check out the managers.py in the following project: [django-model-utils/.../managers.py](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/blob/master/model_utils/managers.py)

It should show you how he implemented the queryset

```
def get_query_set(self):
    qs = super(QueryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(self._q)
    if self._order_by is not None:
        return qs.order_by(*self._order_by)
    return qs
```

Answer (score -1):

If long datasets is your motivation for this question use Redis cache in your Django project.

http://unfoldthat.com/2011/09/14/try-redis-instead.html